# SSIS Script task error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Tags: vb.net, ssis, pdfsharp

I have the following script in SSIS using Pdfsharp library:

---

```
#Region "Imports"
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf
Imports PdfSharp.Pdf.IO
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
#End Region

    Public Sub Main()
        '
        ' Add your code here
        '
        Dim document As PdfDocument
        Dim doc_name As String
        doc_name = "C:\temp\Testfile.pdf"

        document = PdfReader.Open(doc_name)


        document.Info.Author = "TestTest"

        document.Save(doc_name)

        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
```

It's failing with an error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." on PdfReader.Open line. Steps executed: Pdfsharp library is placed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn folder and solution recognizes it. I have access to that file and can open it.  What else can cause this error in this super simple code? Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Is `PdfReader.Open` working correctly with that PDF file in a console application? Which version of PDFsharp? Tried the latest PDFsharp 1.50 RC?

Comment: I'm using latest version of PDFSharp 1.50RC and yes, in console application (VS2017 VB app) it works. It changes PDF metadata (Author) and saves successfully. In the same VS2017 but Intergration services project it fails in script task.

Comment: Any details about the exception that is thrown?